# Python2.7 socket error 37 "Operation already in progress"

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets

I'm making a script that reads a file full of proxy servers and checks if they are up or down.

```
import socket

proxyFile = open("proxies.txt","r");
lines = proxyFile.readlines();

class Colors:
    none = "\033[0m";
    red = "\033[31m";
    green = "\033[32m";
    yellow = "\033[33m";
    blue = "\033[34m";
    purple = "\033[35m";
    cyan = "\033[36m";

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM);
sock.settimeout(3);

for line in lines:
    line = line.replace(":"," : ");
    reader = line.split();
    ip = reader[reader.index(":") - 1];
    port = int(reader[reader.index(":") + 1]);
    try:
        sock.connect((ip,port));
        print Colors.cyan + ip + ":" + str(port) + Colors.none + " is " + Colors.green + "UP";
        sock.close();
    except socket.timeout:
        print Colors.cyan + ip + Colors.yellow + ":" + Colors.cyan + str(port) + Colors.none + " is " + Colors.red + "DOWN";
```

It seems that the file reads fine and the socket creates, but it only connects to one server then it gives the error.

Proxy File:

```
1.0.134.56:8080
1.165.192.248:3128
1.172.185.143:53281
1.179.156.233:8080
1.179.164.213:8080
1.179.185.253:8080
1.192.242.191:3128
1.20.169.166:8080
1.20.179.68:8080
1.20.99.163:8080
```

Comment: You can’t re-`connect` a socket after closing it. Just create a new socket each time through the loop.

Comment: @abarnert Ahh I did not know that, thankyou!

Comment: As a side note: Semicolons are not statement terminators in Python the way they are in C; they're only used to separate multiple simple statements on the same line (which is a very rare thing to need to do). You should not have one at the end of each line.

Comment: Also, whenever possible, you should use `with` statements instead of explicit `close` calls (or instead of not closing the file at all). In Python 3.2+, this works for sockets as well as files. Plus, you don't need to call `readlines` on a file if you just want to iterate the lines; just iterate `for line in file:`.

Comment: @abarnert Thank-you for the tips & info! Also, I use semicolons as an ocd thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't re-[`connect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.connect) a socket. Once it's connected, it's connected. Even if you call [`close`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.close):

> all future operations on the socket object will fail.

The right answer is to create a new socket each time through the loop, whether with [`create_connection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.create_connection) or with [`socket`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket) and `connect`. For example, change your `try` block to this:

```
try:
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM);
    sock.settimeout(3);
    sock.connect((ip,port));
    print Colors.cyan + ip + ":" + str(port) + Colors.none + " is " + Colors.green + "UP";
    sock.close();
except socket.timeout:
    print Colors.cyan + ip + Colors.yellow + ":" + Colors.cyan + str(port) + Colors.none + " is " + Colors.red + "DOWN";
```